# Azure mobile app android EnableQuery[PageSize]

Tags: c#, android, azure-mobile-services

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk

How to do "EnableQuery[PageSize]" on android?

The page tells how to do on server but nothing mentioned about client side.

And android client does not tell me.

I need to fetch about 5000 records and currently android mobile app sdk fetches 50 records by default and does 100 calls. I want to make pagesize to 1000 on android .

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of the Android SDK does not provide the specifics of changing the paging size.  The facilities are there (look up [PullStrategy.java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-android-client/blob/3e1cd0995e301c829514b05b7a2769e63625e81e/sdk/src/sdk/src/main/java/com/microsoft/windowsazure/mobileservices/table/sync/pull/PullStrategy.java) in the repo), but there is no way to hook it into the code.

For right now, you should:

1. [File an issue on the azure-mobile-apps-android-client repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-android-client/issues)
2. Build a custom version of the client - alter the defaultTop value in PullStrategy.java

When we do handle it properly, you will need to let you sub-class IncrementalPullStrategy to be able to specify the page size, then pass in a PullStrategy into the constructor of the sync table.  We are happy to take a PR on this if you work on it.

Comment: do we have android client sdk point of contact? because we have more than one issue and it's critical. :) and will like to have good solution for the project.

Comment: If you have an Azure support contract, then you can submit via that.  If not, then you have access to SO, Azure Forums and the GitHub repo.